# Missing Subsequent Citation?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

[Preface: I'm certain this question has been posed before but I could not find a simplified example as described below. I did find other threads but regarding more complicated formatting....]

With multiple citations I discover that the author is omitted after the initial citation. I seem to encounter this problem specifically with the Chicago style. In other words, alternative styles (i.e. `authoryear` with only `biblatex`) do not yield this problem. MWE as follows,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@Book{book,
  author        = {Author},
  title         = {Booktitle},
  subtitle      = {Booksubtitle},
  publisher     = {Publisher},
  location      = {Location},
  date          = {1995},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

First time \parencite[c.f.][38]{book}. Second time \parencite{book}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

With the output being,

> First time (c.f. Author 1995, 38). Second time ().

While the desired result is obviously,

> First time (c.f. Author 1995, 38). Second time (Author 1995).

This result also occurs when using the `\autocite` command.

Any thoughts or references to other threads in which the answer may be found would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable `biblatex-chicago`'s *ibidem* feature:

```
\usepackage[authordate,noibid,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```