# Bug in the parencite command of the biblatex-chicago package?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I want to use the package `biblatex-chicago` for citations.

I have a file with the following content:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{myBibliography}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\textcite{doe:2013}\\
\parencite[see][p.\ 2]{doe:2013}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the content of the file `myBibliography.bib`:

```
@article{doe:2013,
 author               = {Doe, John},
 month                = {5},
 title                = {The Title},
 yournaltitle         = {The Journal},
 year                 = {2013},
 }
```

Typesetting yields

> Doe (2013)
>   (seep. 2)

However, one should get

> Doe (2013)
>   (see Doe 2013, p. 2)

Can anybody reproduce this result?

Is this due to a bug in the `biblatex-chicago` package?

Comment: I get this behaviour too.  It looks like a bug.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301475/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70738/35864

Answer (score 7):

According to the `biblatex-chicago` documentation this is actually expected and intended behaviour and can be turned off with the preamble option `noibid`.

> **noibid** At the request of an early tester, I have included this option to allow you 
>   globally to turn off the ibidem mechanism that
>   `biblatex-chicago-authordate` uses by default. This mechanism doesn’t
>   actually print “Ibid,” but rather includes only the postnote
>   information in a citation, i.e., it will print (224) instead of
>   (Author 2000, 224). Setting this option will mean that none of these
>   shortened citations will appear automatically.

from § 5.4.3, p. 108, "noibid"
[`biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf)

---

It does look weird though, expecially with pre- and postnotes together.
In that case, one could modify the `cite:ibid` macro to add a space between the pre and the postnote:

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@noibid}%
  {\blx@ibidreset%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}%
  {\ifthenelse{\iffieldundef{prenote}\AND%
      \iffieldundef{postnote}}%
    {\blx@ibidreset%
      \usebibmacro{cite}%
      \PackageWarning{biblatex-chicago}%
      {Empty Ibidem citation}}%
    {\ifboolexpr{not (test {\iffieldundef{prenote}} or test {\iffieldundef{postnote}})}{\addspace}{}\toggletrue{cms@inlineibid}}}}% <--- modify here
\makeatother
```

---

If you want more or less proper ibidem, use this redefinition

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \iftoggle{cms@noibid}%
    {\blx@ibidreset\usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}}
\makeatother
```

---

Compare the output of the following documents.

Standard `\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}`, no modifications.

```
\documentclass[american, ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autopunct=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{testbook,
  author        = {Walter Ordsmith},
  editor        = {Eddie Ditor},
  title         = {The Work},
  subtitle      = {Subtitle},
  date          = {1983},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \textcite{testbook}
  \parencite{testbook}
  \parencite[see][p.\ 2]{testbook}
  \parencite[see][1]{testbook}
  \parencite[2]{testbook}
  \parencite[see][]{testbook}

  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As above with `noibid`: `\usepackage[noibid,authordate,backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}`.

[image]

As above with modifications to `cite:ibid` to add spaces.
[image]

As above with modifications to `cite:ibid` for ibidem.
[image]