# Avoid dropping author-date with chicago citation style and repeated citation with page numbers

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I see a problem where biblatex omits the author name and year in repeated citations when page numbers are used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib} 
@article{denning2010computation,
    AUTHOR      = {Denning, Peter J.},
    TITLE       = {What is Computation?},
    JOURNAL     = {Ubiquity},
    YEAR        = {2010},
    DOI         = {10.1145/1880066.1880067}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}

First citation \autocite[2]{denning2010computation};
second citation \autocite[4--8]{denning2010computation}.

\end{document}
```

This renders as follows:

[image]

But I want it to render as

> First citation (Denning 2010, 2); second citation (Denning 2010, 4-8)

How can I disable the omission of the name and year? Preferred facultatively, but possibly globally.

Comment: Have you tried adding the (global) `noibid` option? What does 'facultatively` mean? (Optionally?) If you mean on an *ad hoc* basis, then compare not loading the `noibid` and for your second `\autocite` putting a `\mancite` first (e.g., `\mancite\autocite[4--8]{denning2010computation}`). If neither of those work, I'll need more explanation of what facultatively means to you.  And of course, there's also `\autocite*{<key>}`, though it will not do what you want out of the box.

Comment: @jon Yes, ad-hoc. Both proposals are perfect, thanks, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is both a global and facultative solution available.

The global solution is to use the `noibid` option at package load time:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate, noibid]{biblatex-chicago}
```

The *ad hoc* solution is to precede your citation commands with `\mancite`:

```
second citation \mancite\autocite[4--8]{denning2010computation}
```

(Note that there is also `\citereset`, which 'resets' even more trackers than `\mancite`. It is most useful if you want to restart citation trackers at the start of the section.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate, 
%noibid % <-- uncomment if you want to disable `ibid` globally
]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib}
@article{denning2010computation,
    AUTHOR      = {Denning, Peter J.},
    TITLE       = {What is Computation?},
    JOURNAL     = {Ubiquity},
    YEAR        = {2010},
    DOI         = {10.1145/1880066.1880067}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}

First citation \autocite[2]{denning2010computation};
second citation 
\mancite % <-- comment out to see default behaviour
\autocite[4--8]{denning2010computation}.

Note that \autocite*[2]{denning2010computation} is unaffected by the \verb+noibid+ option\ldots

\end{document}
```

If you need to use `\mancite` frequently (but not all the time), you might want to define a new citation command for this purpose:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\myautocite}[\mkbibparens]
% this is just the \parencite command (of biblatex-chicago) + \mancite
  {\mancite
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {}%\setunit{\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\myautocites}[\mkbibparens]{\myautocite}%
   {\setunit{\multicitedelim}}

\newrobustcmd*{\Myautocite}{\bibsentence\myautocite}
\newrobustcmd*{\Myautocites}{\bibsentence\myautocites}
```

This gives you `\myautocite`, `\myautocites`, `\Myautocite`, and `\Myautocites`. (Although I am not sure the last two are of much use in  Chicago's author-date citation style.)