# Citations not working properly while using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biber, biblatex-chicago

Biblatex-chicago package doesn't work properly.
I have main file main.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
authordate,%
maxcitenames=2,%
backend=biber,%
]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}
  \section{Section}
  Citation \parencite{colwell06}.
  Citation \parencite[p.~12]{colwell06}.

  Citation \textcite{colwell06}.
  Citation \textcite[p.~12]{colwell06}.
\end{document}
```

and references in refs.bib file:

```
@Book{colwell06,
  author =   {Robert P Colwell},
  ALTeditor =    {},
  title =    {Pentium Chronicles - The people, passion, and politics behind Intel's landmark chips},
  publisher =    {Wiley Interscience},
  year =     {2006}
}
```

For some reason the second citation of parencite doesn't show author of the article at all.
Just the page number is visible and I get following output:

[image: output]

Using normal biblatex package and style=authoryear option instead of authordate I don't get this error. Is there something wrong with chicago package or am I missing something?

Comment: `\parencite` is doing is exactly what the Chicago Manual of Style recommends, i.e. citing a page from the just-cited source only requires the page number.

Comment: More helpfully, you can use the `noibid` option to `biblatex-chicago` to turn of ibidem tracking and hence always produce the full citation.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Bug in the parencite command of the biblatex-chicago package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129487/35864)

Comment: Yeah, your answer in the linked question was good so this is a duplicate. Should I mark this as one somehow?

Comment: I have marked your question as a duplicate.