Cannot cite the same bib entry twice in a row
I'm trying to use biblatex-chicago. For some reason it won't let me cite the same bib entry twice in a row:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@Article{CharnessDufwenberg2006,
  author  = {Charness, Gary and Dufwenberg, Martin},
  journal = {Econometrica},
  title   = {Promises and partnership},
  year    = {2006},
  number  = {6},
  pages   = {1579--1601},
  volume  = {74},
}
@Article{BeattieLoomes1997,
  author  = {Beattie, Jane and Loomes, Graham},
  journal = {Journal of Risk and Uncertainty},
  title   = {The impact of incentives upon risky choice experiments},
  year    = {1997},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {155--168},
  volume  = {14},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah \parencite{CharnessDufwenberg2006}.

Let's see if this works \parencite[\textit{c.f.},][]{CharnessDufwenberg2006}.

It didn't work! Let's cite something else first \parencite{BeattieLoomes1997}.

Now let's try again \parencite[\textit{c.f.},][]{CharnessDufwenberg2006}.

I guess one cannot cite the same thing twice in a row.

\end{document}


Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
The Chicago Manual of Style FAQ says you should do this as appropriate, discouraging the use of "ibidem".
Thanks a bunch!
SOLUTION:
Pass the option noibid to biblatex-chicago.

Not cmslos. ibidtracker. If you set ibidtracker=false, you can workaround the problem at least in the sense that the citations show up. This is an option passed to biblatex, but I can't immediately reproduce it there - ibid or whatever shows up as expected.

Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129487/35864

Thank you, @cfr and @moewe . Apologies to all for not finding the question I duplicated. The option noibid of biblatex-chicago solves the problem. It's worth noting that the Chicago Manual of Style opposes use of "ibidem": https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Documentation/faq0010.html
