"Package biblatex-chicago Warning: Empty Ibidem citation on input line ..." What does this warning mean? How can I correct it?
on several lines throughout my thesis I get the "Package biblatex-chicago Warning: Empty Ibidem citation on input line ...". I googled it but I couldn't find any mentioning of this type of warning. I'm using the following packages (sorry if I posted unnecessary packagaes):
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{... .bib}

I cite with \parencite[][]{}{}{} and also tried the \cite command as an alternative. However, the warning still exists. Further, I can't determine any differences to the majority of citations that work just fine without a warning.

Without an example document that reproduces the problem with as little code as possible and is compilable for everyone on this site, it's hard to say for certain, but I guess you run into the same "issue" as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129487/35864: biblatex-chicago's default behaviour if you cite the same work twice in a row (a situation where other conservative styles would use "ibid.") is not to use "ibid.", but to just print the postnote/page reference. If there is no such thing, the reference comes up empty. This warning tells you about that.

Any news here? As said above, this sounds like expected behaviour.
